# Cleaning up a 'distorted' audio clip?

Tags: sound-effects, sfx, distortion, clean

I'm working on a game, and I'm not the best with finding or making sound effects. I found a bunch of great ones, but they all seem distorted. There's a small echo and it seems a bit electronic-like. How would I begin to clean this up to make it sound somewhat normal?

I believe this audio pack was ripped from a video game, which is probably why they all sound so strange.

Here are three samples:

http://vocaroo.com/i/s0GdIhU2FLQm
http://vocaroo.com/i/s0cCBbB10nc7

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better to find other sound effects...
Or, better yet, make them yourself.
Cleaning those sounds will probably be a lot of work for a non ideal result.
Additionally those sounds may be protected by author´s rights and you could have legal problems using them.

Enjoy the process of your sound effects creation!

Comment: I agree; you need to scrap them and find others, or even try to recreate these ones. Maybe they are intentionally distorted demonstrations and you have to pay for the usable files.